# Select with numc field condition returns no data

Tags: select, return-value, conditional-statements, abap

I want to extract some data from table view SACY_BOOK (which is one of those training tables always implemented in SAP) into my intern table wa_booking, filtered by a numc-field pa_anum. Here's what I got so far:

```
PARAMETERS pa_anum TYPE sacy_book-agencynum.

DATA wa_booking TYPE sacy_book.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  SELECT carrid connid fldate bookid name
    FROM sacy_book
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF wa_booking
      WHERE agencynum = pa_anum.  **<-- this here be the problem **

    WRITE: / ... (I'll skip this part)
  ENDSELECT.
```

Code should work for everyone who has ABAP editor, since it only uses example tables supplied by SAP.

So, debugger shows me that if I choose some company with e.g. agencynum "00000108", this exact number is sent to pa_anum, with zeros in front and everything. Still, my sy-subrc variable gives back a 4, meaning that nothing which fits the condition was found. Hard to believe, since pa_anum gets its values from the same source...

Comment: Have you checked (e. g. using transaction SE16 or SE16N) that the table contains any values at all? Most of the SFLIGHT demo tables are delivered empty and need to be filled with sample data first.

Comment: [vwegert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/218890/vwegert) is probably right. I have checked the content of this table in each and every client of the system I am working on and the table is empty.

Comment: Ding ding ding! ... and now I'm asking myself why SAP only fills half of their stuff. Ah, well, thanks anyway, it works just fine with one out of 8+ possible choices. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo tables are delivered empty - on purpose, because why would you want demo data in your production environment that you won't ever need? Use the program `SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR` to fill the tables `SBOOK` and `STRAVELAG` that make up the view `SACY_BOOK`.

Comment: Heh, didn't even know that it has a generator built in specially for that stuff. Thanks again!